# Save Session variable

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my Session variable.
I want to save a Filter in the Session. So I have a Page for the Filter Form and a page for the List which gets the filter.

When I click the Submit Button for the Filter Page i get directly to the List Page.On this Page i set the Variable with the following code.

```
if($_SESSION['Filter']=="0"){
    getList();    
} else {
    getFilterList($_SESSION['Product'], $_SESSION['Price']);
}

if ( !isset( $_POST['FilterButton'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['Filter']='0';
} else {
    $_SESSION['Filter']='1';
}
```

Now I have the Problem when I refresh the Page the Filter isn't set anymore because the Filter-button of the Form is not clicked.

How can I save now this Variable for ever unless i set a new Filter.?

Comment: Do you use `session_start()`?

Comment: yeah sure i do the problem is not that i cant save the varibale. the problem is that the variable gets 0 when i refresh because i dont hit the submmit button of the filter

Comment: Do you see a lot of `undefined variable` errors in your php error log

Comment: I think you need to read these [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your second if statement is setting the session filter to 0 no matter the case.

Comment: nope The problem is that the refresh because after the refresh the variable gets set 0 what is totally correct but i want to know is there a way that when i click a button i save the session variable and also is the same after refresh. @FabionStephens yeh i saw this but in my code is 1 was a copy failure in my question :D

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Your filter keeps reset because of this:

```
if ( !isset( $_POST['FilterButton'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['Filter']='0';
}
```

You should remove this code and add other button to reset filter. When the reset button will be `isset` then clear filter.

Comment: ok thank you this should solve the problem. Or is there another option without the Reset?

Comment: @Moritz you can also only remove the code above, but then if user would like to reset filter he will need to do it manualy. It can be good solution anyway if you havent a lot of controls in your filter.